# (Python) Google sheet API: append only rows which are not duplicates

Tags: python, google-sheets, duplicates, append, google-sheets-api

I made a script for append values from dataframe to googlesheet as following:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="myspreadsheetid",
                                range="mysheetid").execute()

values = result.get('values', [])

sheet.values().append(
        spreadsheetId="myspreadsheetid",
        range="mysheetid",
        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
        insertDataOption="OVERWRITE",
        body={
            "values": json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values'))
        },
    ).execute()
```

everything works, but now I want to upgrade the script to append only values, which are not duplicates (of columns A and B) of data already existing in the spreadsheet.
I tried to add to script this condition:

```
if(row[0] == values[0] && row[1] == values[1]){
  duplicate = true;
}
```

but I am not sure how to use it properly.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to append the values of `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values'))` to the specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to append the values that the columns "A" and "B" of the values of `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values'))` are not included in the sheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about checking `values` retrieved from `sheet.values().get()` and the inputted values? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
values = result.get('values', [])

sheet.values().append(
        spreadsheetId="myspreadsheetid",
        range="mysheetid",
        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
        insertDataOption="OVERWRITE",
        body={
            "values": json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values'))
        },
    ).execute()
```

#### To:

```
values = result.get('values', [])

obj = {e: True for e in [str(k[0]) + str(k[1]) for k in values]} # Added
v = [r for r in json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values')) if str(r[0]) + str(r[1]) not in obj] # Added

sheet.values().append(
        spreadsheetId="myspreadsheetid",
        range="mysheetid",
        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
        insertDataOption="OVERWRITE",
        body={"values": v}, # Modified
    ).execute()
```

- In this case, an object for searching the duplicate row of the inputted values is created using the values of columns "A" and "B". Using this object, the duplicated rows are removed from the inputted values.

#### Note:

- When I saw your script, I found `range="mysheetid",`. In your situation, `mysheetid` is the sheet name? If that was the actual sheet ID and the sheet name is not the sheet ID, an error occurs. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)